# Course of action to change fields after a PhD?

Tags: phd, postdocs, engineering, changing-fields, physics

A little introduction: I've done some research in interferometry during my MsC, and from then on, my MsC thesis was on optical fiber sensors, then I worked for two companies in sensorization with optical fibers, and now I am enrolling on a PhD on that very subject.

I like photonics, but I feel like I'd want to try something different. I had the option of getting a PhD in quantum optics but decided on this one, in the end (mostly for logistic reasons, and I liked both themes).

Now, I am not sure whether I will have trouble changing fields (within photonics) after specializing so much in one, especially being my research very engineer/application focused and not so much in slightly more fundamental, or even experimental physics.

I've seen similar questions from time to time, but my specific question would be:
Have I specialized too much to change my field after a phd, and what course of action should I start taking NOW in order to keep my doors open after a PhD?

Comment: Photonics and QOQI are so closely related I can't believe you're really asking this.  People often switch from AMO to solid state or nuclear after 3 years or so,  so yes,  you can handle a change to such a similar subfield.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Yes, I am aware that the fields are somewhat closely related. What worries me most is having a very applied/engineering background (working on experimental physics mostly on the application end, with close relationships to companies) and trying to shift to experimental physics on slightly more fundamental research.

My question is not whether I am able to do it, I know I am. It's more whether there will be any demand for someone of my background, even in a related field.